# Is there a way to remove the BNB from cake-lp? and also on a smart contract?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I have a cake-pair of my token, my bnb was stuck because the total supply of my token is 0 due to rebase, I tested my token on mainnet to check the chart for rebasing, then suddenly the total supply of token became 0. The problem is that I can't remove the lp because the token is 0 total and my bnb was stuck.

Also, I accidentally send busd to contract address, is any way to remove or withdraw the busd? I review my contract, it doesn't have any remove function for other token like usdt/busd

Any help?

Comment: Unless the Token pair code were modified the only way to extract BNB would be burning LP tokens. Similarly retrieving BUSD won't be possible unless special coded were added to do so.

Comment: I can't burn lp tokens from pair address contract.